# Chrome extension Content Script not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, reddit

I built a Chrome Extension script that is supposed to run on Reddit.

My script:

```
console.log("hello world");
```

My manifest.json

```
 {
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Desc",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "*://reddit.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "contentscript.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
    "tabs", "*://reddit.com/*", "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

The script doesn't show up in the "Content Script" section in the chrome dev tools. Does anyone have an idea why my extension is not running?

Comment: I don't think the extension will work without a "name" defined in the manifest.

Comment: I removed it for the purposes of this question. I'll edit one back in. @Mottie

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`"*://reddit.com/*"` doesn't match a valid url, you should use `"*://*.reddit.com/*"`

Comment: @Kusha, np, you could go to https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns for more details.